# Having groups of specified user

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Is it possible to get groups of specified user? If it's possible, I need the query please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with this command and able to get the groups name of specified user.

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | select name
```

[image]

Reference : https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/get-groups-in-which-a-user-is-a-member-using-cmd/